# 2 hop ssh running remote sed command( escaping of sed command)

Tags: shell, ssh, sed

I don't typically try this over multiple ssh hops but due to limitations this is my only choice.

I am trying to run the following remote command which works fine like this :

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/host-rsync-key user\@server1 "'sed -i /ADD_NEW_BELOW/a <server>domain</server>' /config.xml"`

Add a second ssh hop to the mix and I think the shell is stripping something and causing the this command to never be executed on server2 but appears to execute on server1 instead.

`ssh -A -t -o  -i ~/.ssh/host-rsync-key user\@server1 ssh  -A -o -i ~/.ssh/host-rsync-key user2\@server2 "'sed -i /ADD_NEW_BELOW/a <server>domain</server>' /config.xml"`

Could anyone provide help on the proper escapes needed for this sed command over ssh? I can run grep commands over 2 hops no problem so I think this is specific to escape characters related to the sed command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [ProxyCommand to the rescue](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20070925181947) (in which you could also set most of your other defaults)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have your quotes wrong.

This may work:

`ssh -A -t -o -i ~/.ssh/host-rsync-key user\@server1 "ssh -A -o -i ~/.ssh/host-rsync-key user2\@server2 sed -i '/ADD_NEW_BELOW/a <server>domain</server>' /config.xml"`

Comment: so I found the answer to this after spending a few hrs poking at it. This works ssh   -A -t -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=50 -i ~/.ssh/host-rsync-key user1\@server1 ssh -A -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=50 -i ~/.ssh/host-rsync-key user2\@server2 "sed -i '/ADD\_NEW\_BELOW/a\\\ \\\<server\\\>$domain\\\<\\\/server\\\>' config.xml"

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue and did some more digging since I didn't want to escape each space in the string. A way to debug this is by trying to echo a string and writing it to a file and see what the string looks like on the remote host. The solution I ended up with, is to use double quotes throughout, and escaping them, i.e.:

```
ssh -A -t -o -i ~/.ssh/host-rsync-key user@server1 "ssh -A -o -i ~/.ssh/host-rsync-key user2@server2 \"sed -i /ADD_NEW_BELOW/a <server>domain</server>\" /config.xml"
```

A similar solution I needed that definitely works, to fire a mysql commandline query over 2 hops:

```
ssh -C user@firsthop "ssh -C user@secondhop \"echo 'SELECT field FROM database.table WHERE term=condition' | mysql -u mysqluser --password=mysqlpassword -B \""
```

Note how I needed even one more string enclosing on the second hop which I could do using single quotes without any escaping of special characters (but from your examaple, I don't think you even need that).